# optimal thresholding for extract hand image

Tags: image-processing

I am working on palm print identification by palm texture and geometry. i want to binarized hand image in preprocessing step for extracting geometry features like palm width and finger width.
 i have used Gaussian filter for reduced noise and Otsu method for thresholding but I could not reach Optimal image! i was wondering if someone help me!

### my database downloaded from "IIT Delhi Touch-less Palm print "

```
I=imread('hand.jpg');
h= fspecial('gaussian', 15,5);
s=imfilter(I,h,'symmetric');
q=graythresh(I)
BW=im2bw(I,q);
```

Comment: can you please share a sample image.

Comment: @Ankit Dixit  sait dont allow me to share image and say my  Reputation is under 10 !i dont know how can i upload image! i must do this code for 500 image and  its necessery for me!

Comment: if you have any dropbox or google drive account upload your images there and share the link of attachments here.

Comment: tnx @Ankit Dixit I'v chosen these samples  of database for 3 different person https://www.dropbox.com/sc/xlbq89daq8ighpd/AADixATtcuYdV3BCl-etRevva

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code and getting some promising result on your dropbox images. you can try it and share your results for further approach.

```
clc
clear all
close all

impath = 'E:\GoogleDrive\Mathworks\irisDEt\HandSeg';
[name,path] = uigetfile({'*.jpg';'*.png'},'mytitle',impath);

im =imread([path,name]);
im = imresize(im,0.5);
gms = 15;

red = im(:,:,1);
redmed = medfilt2(red,[gms,gms],'symmetric');


redmedbw = im2bw(redmed,0.9*graythresh(redmed));
redmedbw = bwareaopen(redmedbw,1500);
redmedbw = imclose(redmedbw,strel('disk',5));

figure,imshow(im,[])
figure,imshow(redmed,[])
figure,imshow(redmedbw,[])
```

My results are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Code for signature estimation of the structure and extraction on critical(peaks and vallys) from the structure:

```
function [sig,xysamp,idx]= signature(bw,prec)
boundry = bwboundaries(bw);

xy = boundry{1};

x = xy(:,1);
y = xy(:,2);



len = length(x);
res = (len/prec);

re = rem(res,2);

if re
    res = ceil(res);
end

indexes = 1:res:len;

xnew = x(indexes);
ynew = y(indexes);

xysamp = [xnew,ynew] ;
cx = round(mean(xnew));
cy = round(mean(ynew));

xn = abs(xnew-cx);
yn = abs(ynew-cy);

% ang = atand(yn./xn);

sig = (xn.^2+yn.^2);
sig = sig/max(sig);

% Critical Points in Signatures.

diffsig = diff(sig);

% pos = zeros(length(diffsig),1);
idx = 1;
for i = 2:length(diffsig)
    if diffsig(i-1)*diffsig(i) <0
        idx = [idx,i];
    end    
end
idx = [idx,i];
```

Here `idx` are the indexes of `xysamp` which gives actual boundry location in the image. the location of peaks and vallys may not be exact as i m doing sampling of boundry and it is a very simple way to approach the structural based problems.

Thank You

Result of critical point extraction:

[image]

Comment: How about sharing the results?

Comment: i had gotten this result but they are not good for tracing boundary and detect valley point and finger tips point of hands. my code is here :

Comment: why dont you try boudary signatures of hand structure to find out vally point i have written a code for it link is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391221/reverse-image-search-implementation/33410196?noredirect=1#comment54614679_33410196

Comment: I had gotten this result but they are not good for extract feature.its important to extract best shape of hand for extract valley point and fingertips point.I said that OTSU method didn't give optimal threshold.is there other way for thresholding??? @Ankit Dixit

Comment: im =imread('4.jpg');
        h = fspecial('disk',10);
        s = imfilter(I,h,'symmetric');
        %% thresholding
        I2=s(:,:,1)>60;
        %% edge detection
        I4=edge(I2,'canny');
    %% find refrense point
    s=size(I);
    r=[0,0];
    for row=s(1):-1:1
        for col=1:s(2)
            if I(row,col)==1
                r=[row,col];
                break
            end
            
        end
        if I(row,col)==1
            r=[row,col];
            break
        end
    end
    b = bwtraceboundary(I,[row col],'W',8);this is my code!@Ankit Dixit

Comment: but the problem of my code is thresholing isn't automatic!@Ankit Dixit

Comment: what is your actual problem.... i m not getting.... above results are generated without manual thresholding.... if you want to estimate position of finger tip u can use many algorithms on above results like hough transformation, as i have suggested signatures in which you can actually estimate location of finger tip. for more accurate detection you can try Gaussian Mixture Models for background subtraction, but then that will be a complex solution, you can also give try to Active Contours.

Comment: @Ankit Dixit i need the best binary picture for extracting feature like finger width, palm with and finger length.
my problem is extracting the best binary picture that close to original picture.i explain in this link:https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c5asfj2zojbnca5/AAAbYQ0lr1bDb41NYqfrXcnsa?dl=0

Comment: @AnkitDixit Dixit i was wondering if you write the matab code  for finger tip and valley point of hand . thanks a lot and i'm so sorry for wasting your time!the image is in follow link! name of image is hand.jpg  !       dropbox.com/sh/c5asfj2zojbnca5/AAAbYQ0lr1bDb41NYqfrXcnsa?dl=0