# Reverse image search implementation

Tags: image, image-processing

I am currently trying to make a site which will contain several images with patterns and shapes (Lets say few squares and circles of various colors and shape in each picture). And I am aiming to provide the user a way to upload their images of the pattern and do a reverse image search to check whether similar pattern image already exists in my site or not. So is there any way to implement the same, either by custom code or by using any third party api/widgets etc?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ashish below is a matlab code for a function which generates signature of a particular binary object's surface, which is nearly size dependent, you can use this concept for matching a shape on different scale.

```
function sig = signature(bw,prec)
        boundry = bwboundaries(bw);

        xy = boundry{1};

        x = xy(:,1);
        y = xy(:,2);

        len = length(x);
        res = (len/prec);

        re = rem(res,2);

        if re
            res = ceil(res);
        end

        indexes = 1:res:len;

        xnew = x(indexes);
        ynew = y(indexes);

        cx = round(mean(xnew));
        cy = round(mean(ynew));

        xn = abs(xnew-cx);
        yn = abs(ynew-cy);

        sig = (xn.^2+yn.^2);
        sig = sig/max(sig);
```

Following is the example of how to use signature function:

```
        clc
        clear all
        close all

        path = 'E:\GoogleDrive\Mathworks\irisDEt\shapes';
        im1 = imread([path,'\3.png']);
        gray1 = ((im1));

        scales = [1,2,3,4];
        gray1 = im2bw(gray1);

        for i = 1:length(scales)
            im = imresize(gray1,scales(i));
            sig = signature(im,25);

            figure,plot(sig)
            fra = getframe();
            image = frame2im(fra);
            imwrite(image,['E:\GoogleDrive\Mathworks\irisDEt\shapes\',num2str(i),'.png'])
        end
```

following is the test image and its signature for changing in size od images which looks similar in shape.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

All above signatures are generated by the code given above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give it a try :-)